# Creating a browser type application for iphone

Tags: iphone, browser

I would like create an application similar to the safari browser, What is the best way to start off with? I want the user to enter a web address on a field (may be UITextField). The application should open up that page, preserving the view of the textfield. What is the method to follow to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the docs:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIWebView

Create a view based application in Xcode, add a UIWebView, UITextField, UIToolbar, hook up some buttons to do things like back, forward, reload, etc.
This is a really simple application, you can find tutorials on using UIWebViews with just a single search.

Comment: ive done it, but i'm afraid to see coneybeare's answer here that apple will reject any such applications.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer the question but is relevant… I just had an app rejected because the user was allowed to enter any url into a uiwebview.  They told me any variable web content should be opened up in safari.

Comment: Did they explain this as an age-restriction issue or a "duplicating functionality of built-in applications" one?

Comment: Apple will definitely reject duplicating safari inside your app

Comment: in the case of my app, it was not exactly a dupe.  My app allowed users to create Templates that they could use in canvasing or surveying.  It included media and questions.  One section was a donate URL where the template could specify the webpage to use in the campaign to accept donations.  Only people who created templates could enter the url, but it was enough to get rejected